# IIS headers of aspx page appear on page sometimes, any idea why?

Tags: asp.net, iis, header

At random this output it occurring at the top of the page. Site is installed on a lot of servers issue only happens on one server.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 24 May 2010 04:18:30 GMT Server:
Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 39611
```

Comment: Strange. Are you able to reproduce it? What sort of conditions make it occur? (High-load?)

Comment: Do you have any custom http modules running?

Comment: Can't work out the conditions yet so can't reproduce it. And yes I am running a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Use a diagnostics tool such as Fiddler to work out exactly what server its happening on, and what page is being requested, what is being responded with, etc. Then replay that request to another server. Should be able to sort out the problem from there.

Comment: Yeah I was going to use Fiddler but because i can't reproduce it, the issue has only been reported to me. So Fiddler is no good to me at the moment.  Looks like I will have to spend more time trying to reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe setup a load test of sorts (outside normal hours), where you can hit all the servers randomly like 100 times, capture the errors and go from there? If you dont have the http request/response content, youre going on a wild goose hunt trying to resolve the problem.